# How to configure multiple brokers in Django and Celery?

Tags: django, celery, amazon-sqs, django-celery, django-settings

Requirement: Django making use of RabbitMQ(Internal) and SQS/Kafka
Both tasks shares common DB/Django models.

Django settings supports only one broker configuration as of Oct 2016

How to have shared tasks with different Queue configurations and broker settings ?

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this? I have a similar use case and I'm not able to find any concrete solutions.

Comment: There are different ways to setup the broker. Have you tried to have 2 different celery apps? You can pass the broker in the constructor directly. I.E. `app1 = Celery(broker='amqp://')` and `app2 = Celery(broker='sqs://.....')`. On top of that, I think you would have to use shared_task http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-the-shared-task-decorator. I haven't tried this but I think it should work.

Answer (score -1):

I used the code below to specify multiple brokers. If I remember correctly, Celery tries them in the specified order and uses the first one working.

Note: The IPs and hostnames used in the example below are for illustration purposes and need to be adapted to your environment.

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'backend.settings')

app = Celery('proj', broker=["redis://redis:6379/0", "redis://192.168.99.100:6379/0", "redis://192.168.99.102:6379/0"])

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```